# How do you disable opening Safari on macOS?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, screen-time

I would like to disable opening Safari on my Mac. I don't want to delete or modify it in any way, I only want to prevent myself from opening the application itself (If I search for it, or try to open it, it shouldn't run).

I tried using Screen Time's Content Restrictions by going to the Content and Privacy Section > Apps > and unchecking Safari.

But Safari still opens when I am distracted and look for it.

Is there any way to stop Safari from opening?

I'm using macOS Catalina. Would updating to Big Sur / higher version help?

Comment: Trying to solve what appears to be a lack of willpower with a technological solution never quite works. Perhaps seeking professional help to move past your impulsive self will help you in other areas of your life.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps configure the Parental Controls to prevent browsing by limiting the websites you can view. (Big Sur may have slightly improved controls than Catalina.)

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl8490d51e/11.0/mac/11.0

Though of course, there's nothing to stop you from turning the controls off.

Ultimately, I would suggest that the best solution is a non-technical one.

Answer (score -1):

To effectively stop Safari from opening, in Terminal type:

`sudo chmod 000 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`

This command effectively makes the Safari executable unreadable and not capable of being run.

Note: This permissions change may be be overwritten the next time Safari is updated by macOS Software Update.

Comment: If this solution is used, will there be any other harm done to the computer? Will other files / security be affected? I don't wish to alter the application in any way, just disable it?

Comment: IconDaemon: Would not your answer require at least disabling SIP before entering the command? Or, at least first booting to macOS Recovery?

Comment: Robert - No. Safari alone will be affected. This command changes permissions on  a single executable file. No other files are touched. If Safari is invoked by clicking on the app itself, or clicking on a URL, an error message is generated. David- I experimented on a duplicate of Safari in Catalina, and it works without interference by SIP.

Comment: I tried the command. I got `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: I'm assuming you're logged into an Administrator account. Are you getting this error _after_ you type in the Administrator password, or before?

Comment: Yes, and after.

Comment: Try duplicating Safari (right mouseclick > Duplicate) and try the method on the duplicate. I didn't want to affect the 'real' version, and I know I don't have SIP disabled on my work laptop. I don't have a Catalina Mac to work on at the moment. Perhaps the Duplicate function gave me ownership of the Safari resources. You might want to try `sudo chown -R /Applications/Safari` to give you ownership of all the files in the Safari resource structure first, the execute the `sudo chmod ...` command.

Comment: I think Safari is on the read-only partition, isn't it? (I can't work out how to tell on Big Sur.) It's got a rootless ACL on it, certainly.

Comment: Why not a simpler: `/usr/bin/sudo chmod 0 /Applications/Safari.app`?

Answer (score -3):

Install another web browser and make it as default. Also remove the Safari shortcut from the dock.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  These surely help, if you could address the part about “ (If I search for it, or try to open it, it shouldn't run).” this would be a super answer.

Comment: The question is about preventing the user from launching Safari, but I think it's clear that he wants to prevent browsing, and not just use a different app.